# Shell: How to change selected text tab color

Tags: shell, xaml, maui, winui

I need to change shell selected tab text color.
I've this code in Styles.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Tertiary900}" />
    <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray200}" />
</Style>
```

This works fine in Android platform:

[image]

but in WinUI I get this:

[image]

It seems as if the TabBarTitleColor and TabBarUnselectedColor properties are ignored in WinUI.

Comment: Could you please help add your **AppShell.xaml** to your post?

Answer (score 0):

On `.NET 7`: Currently on **Windows**, `TabBarForegroundColor` is the only API that appears to do anything.

On `.NET 8`: If users have those other APIs set for Windows those will now start applying correctly to **Windows**.

The tabs are generated from a `WinUI template` so if you need to workaround [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Platform/Windows/TabbedPage/TabbedPageStyle.xaml) before NET8 you can just replace the template here with your own template. Add below code to **Platform/Windows/App.xaml** file.

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabBarNavigationViewMenuItem">
        <NavigationViewItem 
            x:Name="navViewItem"
            Content="Monkey" 
            Foreground="Pink" 
            Background="Green" 
            IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
            MenuItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsSource}"
            Icon="{Binding Icon}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

For more information, you can refer to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Platform/Windows/TabbedPage/TabbedPageStyle.xaml.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.